# If i used setInterval to request data from database, May it damage the server?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I'm trying to develop chat system in php, sql and ajax. I created function by ajax to get messages from database this function its event when window upload, so if i open 2 windows in browser to test the application, I found the messages bu when i send message it appear in just the window which send from not both of the 2 windows. To solve this problem i used setInterval function every 1 second to show messages.
Do this huge requests damage the server ??

Comment: Short answer : No

Comment: so if thousands of chat sessions open, how can i display messages in different windows ?

Comment: I think `setInterval` or `setTimeout` are the only ways.

Comment: yea, i used set [setInterval] but it sends one request per second to the server, what is thousands of chat rooms is open? there will be too many requests in the time, Shall it stop the server working?

Comment: By "thousands" you mean two or more :-) . You need to give each chat an ID, send that ID to each client window in the chat, and then use the ID in subsequent request to identify the chat.

Comment: aha ok, i got it, thnaks

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite know what you meant with "Damage", but nothing can be really damaged by a few extra requests.

If you're wondering whether the webserver can handle the load, it really depends on how many chat sessions are going at the same time. Any decent web server should be able to handle a lot more than two requests per second. If you have thousands of chat sessions open, or you have very CPU intensive code, then you may notice issues.

A bigger issue may be your network latency. If your network takes more than a second for a round-trip communication with the server, then you may end up with multiple requests coming from the same client at the same time.

Comment: side notes: concerns about "damaging" will be on rather other aspects, like filtering possible intrusive code in the messages, and setting some restrictions to avoid flooding (from bots for example)

Comment: so if thousands of chat sessions open, how can i display messages in different windows ?

Comment: sorry, i mean by damage that the server will stop because of too many requests in the same second